# Compile error when calling function

Tags: vba

I keep getting the following error `Compile Error: Expected =` whenever I try to run my VBA code. What is causing it?

```
Function cStatus(cValue, mName)
If mName= True Then
rTotal = rTotal + cValue
ElseIf mName= False Then
rTotal = rTotal - cValue
End If
End Function

Private Sub BE_Click()
checkStatus = cStatus(10, "B_E")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning a return value for your `cStatus` function, so the line `checkStatus = cStatus(10, "B_E")` doesn't know what it is receiving.

```
' Define a return type for the function (I used string).
Function cStatus(cValue, mName) As String
    ' Wrapping True and False in quotes since you are passing a string.
    ' If this is supposed to be a boolean, then type the parameter (see below).
    If mName = "True" Then
        rTotal = rTotal + cValue
    ElseIf mName = "False" Then
        rTotal = rTotal - cValue
    End If

    ' Assign a return value.
    cStatus = "the value"
End Function
```

Alternately, you can make `cStatus` a `Sub` if you do not need to return a value:

```
Sub cStatus(cValue, mName)
    If mName = "True" Then
        rTotal = rTotal + cValue
    ElseIf mName = "False" Then
        rTotal = rTotal - cValue
    End If
End Function

Private Sub BE_Click()
    ' No "checkStatus" variable.

    cStatus 10, "B_E"
End Sub
```

---

As a side note, none of your parameters are typed, so they will all come in as `Variant` passed *by reference* (`ByRef`). I'm not sure if this intended, but it is good practice to type them regardless as most of the time you will want to pass them by value (`ByVal`).

For example:

```
Function cStatus(ByVal cValue As Integer, ByVal mName As Boolean) As String
```